# Call to undefined method Embed\Embed::create() in Laravel 8.83

Tags: php, laravel, package

We have problems when updating our platform to Laravel 8 and php 8.1.10 we use the Embed/embed package and when creating a QRcode from a link provided by the user we have this error:

```
Call to undefined method Embed\Embed::create()
```

We did however check if the package was up to date, it is in version 4.4.4.

It was imported using the namespace feature, and appears that the package is not deprecated.

Here is the problematic code:

```
try {
    $info = Embed::create($url);

    $qr_code->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $qr_code->redirect_to_url = $url;
    $qr_code->title = $info->title;
    $qr_code->description = $info->description;
    $image = ($info->image !== null) ? $info->image: \Czim\Paperclip\Attachment\Attachment::NULL_ATTACHMENT;
    $qr_code->image = $image;
    $qr_code->icon = $info->providerIcon;

    $qr_code->save();

    if ($sl == null) {
        $qr_code->qr = new \SplFileInfo(public_path(\DNS2D::getBarcodePNGPath($qr_code->getUrl(), 'QRCODE', 70, 70, [0, 0, 0])));
        $qr_code->save();
    }

    return redirect('dashboard/qr')->with('message', $msg);

} catch (\ErrorException $e) {
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('redirect_to_url', $e->getMessage());
} catch (\Embed\Exceptions\InvalidUrlException $e) {
    $validator->getMessageBag()->add('redirect_to_url', $e->getMessage());
}
```

I can't find out if the create method is no longer available in version 4

Can you help us with that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check requirements for version 4.4.4 in this link: https://packagist.org/packages/embed/embed#v4.4.4

Comment: The ::create method seems to be in v3 only. The v4 equivalent would seem to be `$embed = new Embed(); $info = $embed->get($url);`. Take a look at https://github.com/oscarotero/Embed/tree/v4.4.4 for docs on the version you are using